# LEDs, PWM and Max Current

Tags: led, current, pwm

LEDs typically specify Peak Current as something like 100mA @ duty cycle = 10%, and a "Test Condition" (I_F, i.e. Continuous Current) current of, for example, 20mA. That's a 2-dimensional constraint though. Is there some rule that dictates how much current an LED can handle up to some higher duty cycle given the extremes? I've never seen a 2-D graph relating maximum current to PWM duty-cycle in any LED datasheet... for example [this one](http://www.taydaelectronics.com/datasheets/A-1094.pdf).

Comment: IIRC it drops off inverse logarithmically. But don't quote me on that.

Comment: If you have a particular LED in mind, it would be very helpful if you post it. There might be a pulse current rating lurking somewhere in the datasheet.

Comment: @DrRobotNinja I've added a datasheet link

Comment: This is my interpretation of the datasheet you provided: The peak current is 100 mA and you cannot exceed it. Furthermore, if you want to run 100 mA, you have to do so at 10% duty cycle or less, and the frequency must be at least 1 kHz. You could probably get away with a higher current, but the LED would be out of spec.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're talking about interpolating, you're probably reasonably safe. For example, if 100mA is okay at 10% and 30mA continuous is okay, [then](https://web.archive.org/web/20140625220258/http://www.horrorseek.com/home/halloween/wolfstone/Lighting/litlpo_PoweringLEDs.html)

[image]

Extrapolating is **not** safe. There are many different kinds of failure modes, and the one that is dominant at 10% duty cycle (perhaps thermal effects on the die) is not likely the same one that is dominant at 1% duty cycle (perhaps electromigration or bonding wire heating). You just can't tell. And it could manifest itself as a failure in a short time, or it might degrade the life so it's hundreds of hours.

Here are some examples from Cree of electromigration failures:

[image]

If you're looking for LEDs that will have a reasonable life with short duty cycles, you might consider the ones rated for flash use.

Cree has an excellent [AN](http://www.cree.com/%7E/media/Files/Cree/LED%20Components%20and%20Modules/XLamp/XLamp%20Application%20Notes/XLampPulsedCurrent.pdf) on pulsed over-current driving of their XLamp LEDs.

It says, for example:

> A particular device subjected to Figure1 4 pulsed over-current driving
> repeated transients at an amplitude some
> percentage above the data-sheet limits but below the threshold
> required for single-pulse failure will still eventually fail. The
> failure mechanism will most likely be due to electromigration as
> enough metal ions are eventually shifted away from their original
> lattice positions. The other factor that can lead to a reduced
> lifetime is excessive heating of the p-n junction, which causes the
> LED’s output to degrade below 70 percent of its original luminous
> flux.

Their conclusion leads to the following guidelines:

> Based on the 1-KHz pulse testing we have reviewed in this application
> note, Cree suggests the following guidelines for pulsed current
> operations:
>
> 1. For duty cycles between 51-100%, do not exceed 100% of the maximum rated current;
> 2. For duty cycles between 10-50%, do not exceed more than 200% of the maximum rated current;
> 3. For duty cycles less than 10%, do not exceed more than 300% of the maximum rated current

Those are guidelines, not specifications, and are not guarantees by Cree, nor would they necessarily apply to any other manufacturer's products.

I can say that I've done some testing of LEDs under pulsed conditions, which I cannot share due to NDA requirements, but I don't find the Cree guidelines especially surprising.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some rule that dictates how much current an LED can handle up to some higher duty cycle given the extremes? I've never seen a 2-D graph relating maximum current to PWM duty-cycle in any LED datasheet...

There is no rule other than what the manufacturer shows in their datasheet. The Manufacturer, having the best access to the source material, a full understanding of their own production and test methods, will have tested the batches to provide the best (Read: Most Profitable) performance at constant or pulsed current/brightness/lifetime. No sense in testing say 500mA at 20% if it will die in a few hours.

That said, the 100mA @ 10% is for the stated Lifetime of the LED. You could try a higher current at a longer duty cycle.